# How to open notepad.exe and Pass some data into it from Java?

Tags: java

I opened notepad.exe using Java ProcessBuilder but I cannot pass text into it using the OutputStream. Following is my code:

```
public class Notepad {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("notepad.exe");
    Process process=pb.start();

    OutputStream d=process.getOutputStream();

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    while(sc.hasNext()){
            d.write(sc.nextInt());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? Please be precise...

Answer (score 6):

Notepad takes a file as an argument.  Here is how you could call it from the command line:

```
notepad.exe C:/path/to/my/file/tmp.txt
```

Here is what your Java code call might look like:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("Notepad.exe", "C:/path/to/my/file/tmp.txt");
pb.start();
```

Notepad [does not provide many command line arguments](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/notepadexe-command-line-options/810760c1-a45a-4013-9544-1c1208e1b389). There is nothing for constructing a new document from a given string, so this is the closest you can get.

Comment: But you may create a file first, then open it with the Notepad. Will look like you passed the text to it

Comment: @fedd It will look similar, but not identical. When you open a new document in Notepad, it's untitled and it knows that if any content is entered that it should present a save prompt before the window is closed. When you open an existing file, it will prompt only if the content changes. So the semantics are slightly different.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. But I have one more query. Can I type into notepad using OutputStream, like I press a key and at the same time it types into notepad, as if it is being typed from keyboard?

Comment: @PunyaKotecha Nope, sorry